# HTTP Status 406 with spring mvc jqgrid

Tags: spring, jqgrid, integration

i am trying to load the model data into jqgrid in spring mvc application. Its working fine in another Spring MVC Application with the following code and dependencies,but its not working for me,i am getting the following error.
 **406 error(HTTP Status error)**:The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
Please do the needful.

```
     **more data:**

       Spring Version :<spring.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>

      Spring Security Version:
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
      Java Version:<java.version>1.8</java.version>


       **Controller:** 


          @RequestMapping(value = "/getPackageList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
                    public @ResponseBody CustomResponse getPackageList( ) {
                        List<Customize> customize = Customize.findAllCustomize();
                        System.out.println("Comes here to fetch list");     
                        CustomResponse response = new CustomResponse();
                        response.setCustomize(customize);
                        response.setRecords(String.valueOf(customize.size()));
                        response.setPage("1");
                        response.setTotal("10");
                        //System.out.println("response::::"+response);
                        return response;
                    }


        **pom.xml**



        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.13</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.13</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                 <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                 <version>2.2.3</version>
                </dependency>

    **JQGrid:**

        <script>
            $(function() {
                  $("#grid").jqGrid({
                   url:'${pageContext.request.contextPath}/superAdmin/getPackageList',
                   datatype: 'json',

                   mtype: 'GET',
                   colNames:['Basepackage','Details','Cost','Duration'],
                   colModel:[         
                       {name:'basepackage',index:'basepackage', width:49,sortable:true,sorttype:'int'},
                       {name:'details',index:'details', width:49,sortable:false},
                       {name:'cost',index:'cost', width:49,sortable:false} ,
                       {name:'duration',index:'duration', width:49,sortable:false} 

                      ],
                   getData: {
                   },
                   rowNum:10,
                      rowList:[5,10,15,20],
                      height: 200,
                      autowidth: true,
                      rownumbers: false,
                      pager: '#pager',
                      sortname: 'basepackage', 
                      caption:"Package List",
                      viewrecords: true,
                      ignoreCase: true,
                      sortorder: "asc",
                      emptyrecords: "Empty records",
                      loadonce: true,
                      loadComplete: function() {
                   },
                      jsonReader : {
                          total: "total",
                          page: "page",
                          records: "records",
                          root: "customize", 
                          repeatitems: false,
                          cell: "cell",
                          id: "basepackage"
                      }
                  });
                  $("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
                            {edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:true},
                            { },
                                  { },
                                  { }, 
                            { 
                                sopt:['cn', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'eq', 'bw', 'ew'],
                                   closeOnEscape: true, 
                                    multipleSearch: false, 
                                     closeAfterSearch: true }
                          ); 

                          $("#btnFilter").click(function(){
                           $("#grid").jqGrid('searchGrid',
                             {multipleSearch: false, 
                              sopt:['cn', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'eq', 'bw', 'ew']}
                           );
                          }); 



                 });

            </script>

             Reviewed Patches



             <div id="jqgrid">
                <table id="grid"></table>
                <div id="pager"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Paste the complete error log. And this is not a server side problem by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Controller is returning json your request to the server has to contain header `Accept:application-json`. Make sure it is set by the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to your dispatcher servlet.xml